# to copy a form to another application

Tags: c#

I create a simple application named "A";
in A.Form1  I create a button.
when I click button1 , it raise a message "Hello"; ( I involve MessageBox.Show in there)

I create another application say it's name "B"
I just copied the A.Form1 designer and code and place to B.Form1 designer and code.
The problem is when I run B ,the button1 in B does'nt work.

How the right way to copy forms in A application  to application B ,and the whole controls work.

thank you
pablo

Comment: Why are copying it? Just reference the other assembly and use it.

Comment: Have you copied the MessageBox show code?

Answer (score 0):

When you created `Form1` you subscribed to the `button1.Click`. (as u dbl clicked the btn to add the statement's)

But in case of `Form2` the `button1.Click` was not subscribed.
You can add the missing Click event subscription on `Form_Load` event

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but if the button doesn't work check the mapping and see what is missing...

use the navigate and see what code handles the click.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the code in form A in form B

Code in form A

```
public static void displayMessage() {
   MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
}
```

Code in form B

```
private void showMessage() {
    FormA.displayMessage();
}
```